# rxjs get list of people typing

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I have a messaging system in my application that uses socket-io to allow users to send instant messages to eachother.

I have a service which detects when they are typing.

```
const userTyping = this.instantMessageService
  .messageTyping;

userTyping.subscribe(message => console.log(message.username))
```

I want the other users to be able to see a list of who is typing them a message which times out.

So if one person starts typing they will see "John Doe is typing a message" - this will timeout a couple of seconds later.

In the meantime, if another users starts typing they will see "John Doe and Bill Bloggs are typing a message" and so on.

I've tried messing around with merge, window, buffer etc in rxjs but can't seem to tie it all together.

Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can push the result to an array and map throw it to show who is typing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `[reduce][1]` and concat the item in the reduce.